# How do I stop it from looping endlessly

Tags: c++, while-loop

So below is my while loop code. Loop is endless when I enter anything other than double for cin. How do I make it so that "cout << "  Invalid! Please enter the correct amount.  " only comes once and that it asks for cin straight after that.?

```
int main ()

double pWeekdays7am_7pm;

cout << "\n  Please enter the amount of electricity (kWh) produced in the following time        periods. If no electricity was produced, enter \"0\"" << endl << endl;

      cout << "      Monday-Friday (7am-7pm)  ";
      cin >> pWeekdays7am_7pm;
      while (pWeekdays7am_7pm < 0)
        { cout << "  Invalid! Please enter the correct amount.  " ;
          cin >> pWeekdays7am_7pm;
```

Comment: what type is `pWeekdays7am_7pm`?

Comment: Check the result of the input operation.

Comment: Ask yourself what happens if `cin` ends up in an error state.

Comment: Please add enough code so it compiles.

Comment: Just a tip: compile all your code always with "-Wall -Wextra -pedantic". Those warnings are an invaluable help to identify trouble spots.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think the problem is much more simple and fundamental than that... he is seemingly having trouble clearing the stream buffer should cin fails to eat up the characters in it...

Comment: @ji Someone else already pointed that one out....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you still have the problem a solution to the problem you have would be the following:

```
#include <limits>           // require for limits
#include <iostream>         // required for I/O functionality

using namespace std;        // to avoid using std:: all the time.

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    double pWeekdays7am_7pm;

    cout << "\n  Please enter the amount of electricity (kWh) produced " <<
            "in the following time periods. If no electricity was " <<
            "produced, enter \"0\"" << endl << endl;

    cout << "\tMonday-Friday (7am-7pm)  ";
    cin >> pWeekdays7am_7pm;
    /*
       condition to advance, we check for two things
            1) if the conversion to *double* failed, hence cin.fail will return *true*
            2) if the converted value is within our limits (>= 0)
    */
    while (cin.fail() || pWeekdays7am_7pm < 0) {
        cout << "\tInvalid value! Please enter the correct amount: " ;
        /* reset the stream state */
        cin.clear();
        /* truncate existing contents up to new line character */
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cin >> pWeekdays7am_7pm;
    }
    /* finally return */
    return 0;
}
```

The comments should be pretty straight forward to explain what this code does but should you have any more questions update here and I'll try to answer. I would suggest picking some online resources or a good C++ book and read it.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Yes, you're right about everything you said. Thanks for the advice and for the answer.

Comment: @user129127 No problem, glad to be of assistance! Take care!

Comment: -1 for the condescending, lecturing tone. And you're incorrect that a mod will eventually edit the question to conform to submission guidelines.

Comment: @CareyGregory mods usually edit posts to clear them up and conform with the sub. guidelines unless they are way too vague; hence they flag it (which apparently happened in this case). Tone is used to highlight stuff and at least my answer was satisfactory to OP. Take care!

Comment: No, that's not how moderation works. Mods don't go around editing posts to make them fit guidelines and they don't flag posts. You might notice that the question has been closed and no mods were involved. I recommend you find out how moderation works here. And the only thing that a condescending, lecturing tone highlights is your rudeness.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << "Enter positive number, or 0\n";
cin >> pWeekdays7am_7pm;
if (pWeekdays7am_7pm < 0)
{
    cout << "  Invalid! Please enter the correct amount.  ";
    while (pWeekdays7am_7pm < 0)
    {
        cin.sync(); cin.clear();  //  get rid of anything unwanted
        cin >> pWeekdays7am_7pm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Functionally equivalent to what the OP wrote; ie, it's an infinite loop if `cin` ends up in an error state.

Comment: This will not result in an infinite loop, because of the sync() and clear() to cin... unless I am missing something?  Also I thought he wanted to see his "Invalid..." error message only once, and that was the main issue.

Comment: Did you add those after posting? I don't see an edit indicator but I would swear they weren't there when I added my comment. Anyway, they're there now so disregard my comment.

Comment: ; {   I did an edit but I think they were already there.  Good catch if I missed them initially!